# Unable to connect to remote MySQL from a docker on Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, docker

After much groping in the dark, I think I may have uncovered an `Ubuntu` Desktop specific `docker` issue. Please take note of the following:

- I work at a large corporation where my laptop is connected to internal network (that houses a remote `MySQL` db). My laptop runs `Ubuntu` Desktop OS (v14.04).
- I can connect to the remote `MySQL` server (using `mysql -u<username> -p<password> -h<host>`) command from my laptop. I can also `telnet` to the `MySQL` server on port 3306 (`MySQL` server's default port).

Now, I have a `ubuntu:latest` `docker` container running on my laptop where neither of `mysql` or `telnet` commands to the said `MySQL` server work. I initially thought, this may be due to IP forwarding not enabled, so I uncommented line `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, but to no avail.

Also, note that I do not encounter the same problem on `Ubuntu` server OS (again, to reiterate, I'm running `Ubuntu` Desktop OS on my laptop).

I do not encounter the same problems if I run the `docker` container on a `Mac` machine. So, clearly it is something specific to `Ubuntu` Desktop OS.

Also, this cannot be related to `MySQL` privileges since I can connect to the `MySQL` server from my laptop.

Would anyone know why this is the case?

Thanks.

Comment: you probably should be asking in linux or ubuntu or server fault or something, but when you uncomment out ```net.ipv4.ip_forward=1``` it doesn't do anything unless you restart. If you want the changes to take affect immediately, you have to ```echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward```

Comment: @PressingOnAlways: I did restart the laptop after commenting out the line.

Comment: Can you telnet to the port and IP and see the MySQL hello string?

Comment: Is it possible that the Ubuntu Desktop version runs a firewall (ufw or iptables) by default? Are you able to show the output of the iptables nat, mangle, and filter tables?

Comment: See the official Docker installation instruction for Ubuntu which gives a few instructions regarding the firewall https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#enable-ufw-forwarding